# Emacs: I want to highlight the numbers that my variables contain, no the name of the variables by itself

Tags: emacs

so, I added this to my theme:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
        '(("\\([0-9]+\\)" . font-lock-warning-face)))
```

so far so good... it changes the color of what the variable contain. ex:

```
int a = 5
```

where the '5' is colored with a predefined color. the problem goes when I have a variable whose name correnspond to "variable_1" it colors the '1' in "variable_1"... is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't see how the code snippet you provided could produce the result you're talking about.  Did you perhaps include the wrong snippet?

Comment: sorry, I commit a mistake while I was writting the code... this is the real code from my theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was tested on the following three (3) examples:

- int a = 5
- funtion(1, 2)
- variable_1

```lisp
(defun my-c-mode-keywords ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil (list
    (list "[^_]\\([0-9]+\\)" '(1 'font-lock-warning-face))) 'prepend))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-keywords)
```

Comment: This solve the problem! the only thing now is that in c when I have a funtion or something it colours the character before. ex: funtion(1, 2) the '(' it's being coloured too... do you know why this is happening... Thanks for everything!!!

Comment: Whenever you get a chance, please test out the edit to the answer above -- moving the exclusion outside the capturing group seems to work for all three situations now.

Comment: Dude you are a life saver :D it worked! thanks! I'm working on a sublime text theme for my emacs and I'm strugglin a little bit with the behavior of the theme in some of the programming languages... Thanks a lot for your help!!!