# I want to exclude a character in the keywords of a mode in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

let's say that I have a line of code in ruby like this:

```
example.new()
```

and I have something like this in my theme:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'ruby-mode
        '(("\\([.][a-zA-Z]+\\)" . font-lock-constant-face)))
```

The objective is to highlight with a especific color the 'new' but not the '.' in this line of code. Is there a way to archive this result?

Comment: Before taking a stab at just `example.new()`, do you have some other variations that you would like the regex to *also* cover -- e.g., something in between the parentheses that might appear or something else you can think up as a potential example?  Here is a rough draft:  `"[a-zA-Z]+[.]\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)()"` -- highlighting just the number 1 grouping similar to the example in the following link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33020661/2112489

Comment: I would  like to highlight whatever is between parentheses so the parameters have a different format acording to my theme... example: example.new(1, 2) where the 1 and 2 have an especific format... is there a way to archieve this?

Comment: Here is a rough draft based on your comment above:  `"[a-zA-Z]+[.]\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)(\\([0-9]+\\),\s+\\([0-9]+\\))"` -- using the same method as the previous answer in the above-mentioned link, you can add groups 2 and 3 -- i.e., after `'(1 'font-lock-warning-face)` you can add `'(2 'font-keyword-face) '(3 'font-lock-constant-face)`  If you are trumping other faces that have already been laid, it may be necessary to add a `t` after the name of the face for each group to force a trump to occur; and, you may also need to adjust the order in which the various faces are applied so subsequent trumps.

Comment: thanks, man!!! have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the match of `.` out of the group and then only highlight the group:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'ruby-mode
        '(("[.]\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)" 1 font-lock-constant-face)))
```

Since your regex uses a parenthetical group `\\(...\\)` you can refer to it in your highlight: the `1` thus refers to the part matched by the first (in your case only) group of your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks!!! just a little question: what's the difference in using '1' and '.' before the face that you want to highlight the keyword?

Comment: `'("regex" 1 face-name)` is equivalent to `'("regex" . (1 face-name))`. If you check `C-h v font-lock-keywords`, you'll find the documentation of the supported formats for regex-based highlighting; one of the possibilities is `(MATCHER . FACENAME)` and another one is `(MATCHER . HIGHLIGHT)`. The first one is the one you use in your original version and the second one is used in my answer. Both times, the `MATCHER` is a regex. `HIGHLIGHT` can have different forms, one of them being `(SUBEXP FACENAME)`. If you put all of that together, it only looks superficially like replacing a `.` with a `1`.